# how to set an environment variable value while calling a python script using bash in a single command

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I would like to execute a python file app.py like below:

```
python app.y
```

But I would like to pass to this file a new value = 'ok' for the env variable called 'training'.

How can I do this from shell with a single command?

Comment: Try `env training=ok python3 app.py`, but using command-line arguments is usually a better way to go, as @pavelsaman suggests.

Comment: Just invoke it as `training=ok python3 app.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach should be a little different:

1. set an environment variable: `$ export training=ok`
2. inside your Python script, read the environment variable:

```py
import os

print(os.getenv('training'))
```

Another option would be to use parameters and parse them with something like [argparse](https://pypi.org/project/argparse/).

Comment: This has the potentially unwanted effects of permanently replacing any old value of the variable in the shell, and exposing it to all child processes.